# How to split a file with 250k columns vertically?

Tags: unix, awk

I need to split a file with 250k based on the size (preferable) or number of columns to several (~5) chunks. I am aware of `split` command for row-wise splitting, but don't know if there is any similar function to split column-wise.
The number of columns in my file are not even, so the chunks cannot have equal number of columns.

Input:

```
AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH II JJ KK LL MM
NN OO PP QQ RR SS TT UU VV WW XX YY ZZ
```

Desired output:

`File1`

```
AA BB CC DD        
NN OO PP QQ
```

`File2`

```
EE FF GG HH
RR SS TT UU
```

`File3`

```
II JJ KK LL MM
VV WW XX YY ZZ
```

Comment: What about scripting [cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk, you can adjust n to the number you expect.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
         printf (i%n==0||i==NF)?$i RS:$i FS > "File" int((i-1)/n+1) ".txt"
      }' n=5 file
```

Comment: OP stated `The number of columns in my file are not even`

Answer (score 2):

Use `cut`. It's part of GNU coreutils.

Assuming your input file columns are separated by a space:

```
cut -d " " -f1-4 /path/to/input/file > file1

cut -d " " -f5-8 /path/to/input/file > file2

...
```

See the man page `man cut` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `awk` for this. Not sure if you would like to have 5 columns per file as you mentioned that you have 250k columns that would make creating 50k files, but here is something to get you started:

```
awk '{
  y=1
  for(i=1;i<NF;i++) { 
    if(i%5==0) {
      print $i > "text"y".txt"
      y+=1
      continue 
    }
  printf "%s ",$i >"text"y".txt"
  } 
print $NF > "text"y".txt"}' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH II JJ KK LL MM
NN OO PP QQ RR SS TT UU VV WW XX YY ZZ

$ awk '{
  y=1
  for(i=1;i<NF;i++) { 
    if(i%5==0) {
      print $i > "text"y".txt"
      y+=1
      continue 
    }
  printf "%s ",$i >"text"y".txt"
  } 
print $NF > "text"y".txt"}' file

$ head text*
==> text1.txt <==
AA BB CC DD EE
NN OO PP QQ RR

==> text2.txt <==
FF GG HH II JJ
SS TT UU VV WW

==> text3.txt <==
KK LL MM
XX YY ZZ
```