# Split csv file vertically using command line

Tags: python, bash, csv, command-line, command

Is it possible to split a csv file, vertically, into multiple files? I know we can split single large files into smaller files with no of rows mentioned using the command line. I have csv files in which columns are repeating after certain column no and I want to split that file column-wise.Is that possible with the command line, If not then how can we do it with python?

For Eg.
[image]

consider above sample in which site and address present multiple times vertically, I want to create 3 different csv files containing single site and single address

Any help would be highly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: you might be interested in taking a look at the `cut` command

Comment: indeed [cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)#Examples) is your friend. Please provide an actual input example if you want an adapted solution

Comment: @ishahak, I just edited the question, So basically I want to convert such files to multiple files and each file should contain only 2 rows i.e. site and address

Comment: [Split dataframe into multiple output files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002021/split-dataframe-into-multiple-output-files)

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, please accept it. It is a good habit...

Comment: @ishahak, I have this good habit, Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your input files is named `~/Downloads/sites.csv` and looks like this:

```
Google,google.com,Google,google.com,Google,google.com
MS,microsoft.com,MS,microsoft.com,MS,microsoft.com
Apple,apple.com,Apple,apple.com,Apple,apple.com
```

You can use *cut* to create 3 files, each containing one pair of company/site:

```
cut -d "," -f 1-2 < ~/Downloads/sites.csv > file1.csv
cut -d "," -f 3-4 < ~/Downloads/sites.csv > file2.csv
cut -d "," -f 5-6 < ~/Downloads/sites.csv > file3.csv
```

Explanation:

For the *cut* command, we declare the comma (,) as a separator, which splits every line into a set for 'fields'.

We then specify for each output file, which fields we want to be included.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

If the site-address pairs are regularly repeated, how about:

```
awk '{
    n = split($0, ary, ",");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i += 2) {
        j = (i + 1) / 2;
        print ary[i] "," ary[i+1] >> "file" j ".csv";
    }
}' input.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script produces what you want (based on the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867847/how-to-split-a-file-with-250k-columns-vertically#21870803) adjusted for your needs: number of columns, field separator). It splits the original file vertically into 2 column chunks (note `n=2`) and creates 3 different files (`tmp.examples.1`, `tmp.examples.2`, `tmp.examples.3` or whatever you specify for the `f` variable):

```
awk -F "," -v f="tmp.examples" '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf (i%n==0||i==NF)?$i RS:$i FS > f "." int((i-1)/n+1) }' n=2 example.txt
```

If your `example.txt` file has the subsequent data:

```
site,address,site,address,site,address
Google,google.com,MS,microsoft.com,Apple,apple.com
```